# Loading external audio file in Android

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android and Java. I can load the "testfile.mp3" using the following code if the file is already in my resource folder:

```
mSoundId = mSoundPool.load(MainActivity.this, R.raw.testfile, 1);
```

How can I load a similar file from external folder outside the app document dicrectory (Say under sdcard/Android/data/com.jorc.audio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the [Android MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html). There are examples like play from App Resources:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.testfile);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Or playing a file from the SD Card:

```
//Insert the Path here 
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath())+"/Android/data/com.jorc.aud/test.mp3"); 
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

But to access the SD Card you need the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I had to remove .getPath()) to move to the next line where I also get this error Error:(123, 35) error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: @Amir when you get this error you must put it in a try catch block.

Comment: Well I guess that falls out of my skill. Would you have a sample code with json post request for version 23? The  old ones uses Apache.http which doesn't seem to be supported in New versions.

Comment: @Amir I like this library (https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http). There are lots of examples, like how make a post request or something

Comment: That seems like a great library Timia, Thanks

Comment: @Amir no problem. If you have another question, you can ask me on telegram. Same username as here